# Ruby script is not picking up sourced env vars

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am using environment variables in a Ruby script. When I export the variables and run the script as follows, it works fine.

```
export ELK_URL="https://localhost:3241"
ruby ./my_script.rb
```

The contents of `my_script.rb` are:

```
puts "#{ENV["ELK_URL"]}"
```

However, when I put the environment variables in file and `source` the file, it does not work.

```
source ./my_env # contains ELK_URL
ruby ./my_script.rb
```

The contents of `my_env` are:

```
export ELK_URL="https://localhost:3241"
```

I verified that `source` has set the variables correctly by running the following.

```
echo $ELK_URL
```

Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Comment: If you aren't `export`ing the variable, then sourcing the file will only make it available to the current environment AFAIK

Comment: I tried ```export```ing but still the ruby script is not picking them.

Comment: It works for me when I try it.

Comment: We're unable to reproduce what you are seeing (it seems to work as you'd want it to work).